# Whats the correct way to use a date parameter in WHERE clause

Tags: oracle, plsql, parameters

Whats the correct way to use a parameter for

```
 WHERE WORKS_ORDER_HEADER.DATEREQ < TO_CHAR('DD/MM/YYYY', '&CUT_OFF_DATE')
```

The data is presented in `16/06/1995` format

So if the parameter is less than that date, show all prior dates

Comment: please edit your question and  describe the problme in a question and not in the header. example data and expected results would help to understand  your problem

Comment: Describe your table structure as well, so we can easily understand your problem and propose a solution

Comment: @HammadSajid It is a load of orders essentially and want to show all where the date field is less than the date entered as a parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE date_collumn <= TO_DATE(:PARATEMER, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Why would you try and compare CHAR when you could compare dates.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are looking for:

```
WHERE WORKS_ORDER_HEADER.DATEREQ < TO_DATE('&CUT_OFF_DATE', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

This will of course work only, if your DATEREQ is of type DATE.